# Next JS Sentry Sourcemaps only results app:///_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-26ab5cc38905b883.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sentry

This next js project is a project that uses static build. I want to display which code causes the error to occur. When I develop locally, it displays successfully, but when I build (`next build`), sentry gives results like `app:///_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-26ab5cc38905b883.js` without explaining where the error was found.

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const { version } = require('./package.json');
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const { withSentryConfig } = require('@sentry/nextjs');

const isStaticBuild = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

const config = async () => {
  const folderVersion = await fs
    .readFile('./build.dot', {
      encoding: 'utf-8',
    })
    .catch(() => null);

  return {
    productionBrowserSourceMaps: false,
    output: 'export',
    compiler: {
      // ssr and displayName are configured by default
      styledComponents: true,
      relay: {
        // This should match relay.config.js
        src: './',
        artifactDirectory: './__generated__',
        language: 'typescript',
      },
      reactRemoveProperties: { properties: ['^data-custom$'] },
      ...(isStaticBuild && {
        removeConsole: {
          exclude: ['error'],
        },
      }),
    },
    experimental: {
      swcMinifyDebugOptions: {
        compress: {
          defaults: true,
          side_effects: false,
        },
      },
      modularizeImports: {
        '@mui/material': {
          transform: '@mui/material/{{member}}',
          preventFullImport: true,
        },
        '@mui/icons-material': {
          transform: '@mui/icons-material/{{member}}',
          preventFullImport: true,
        },
        '@mui/lab': {
          transform: '@mui/lab/{{member}}',
          preventFullImport: true,
        },
      },
    },
    swcTraceProfiling: true,
    swcMinify: false,
    publicRuntimeConfig: {
      version,
    },
    sentry: {
      hideSourceMaps: true,
      autoInstrumentServerFunctions: false,
      widenClientFileUpload: true,
    },
    images: {
      unoptimized: true,
    },
    assetPrefix: isStaticBuild && folderVersion ? `/${folderVersion}` : '',
    trailingSlash: true,
  };
};
const withBundleAnalyzer = require('@next/bundle-analyzer')({
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === 'true',
});

const sentryWebpackPluginOptions = {
  silent: true, // Suppresses all logs
};

module.exports = async () => {
  const nextConfig = await config();
  return withSentryConfig(
    withBundleAnalyzer(nextConfig),
    sentryWebpackPluginOptions,
  );
};
```

Is there anything that can still be improved about my configuration?